# <option> select pick the inside text not the value

Tags: php

I have a `<select>` form and I want to pick the selected text.

```
 <select multiple name="detaliicomanda[]"  class='main'  >
 <option value=' '> -- </option>
 <option value='canapea'> Canapea  </option>
 <option value='fotoliu'> Fotoliu </option>
 <option value='seturi'> Seturi </option>
 <option value='coltar'> Coltar  </option>
 <option value='mobila'> Mobila  </option>
 <option value='corpurimobila'> Corpuri Mobila  </option>
</select>
```

I know that if I change the value with the inside option text, the php will pick the text.

i need the value inside the option to be "X" and pick data from selected option

hope you guys understand what i mean :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1:** To get value of a selected option from select tag:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['Color'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

**Example 2:** To get value of multiple select option from select tag, name attribute in HTML  tag should be initialize with an array [ ]:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Color[]" multiple> // Initializing Name With An Array
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// As output of $_POST['Color'] is an array we have to use foreach Loop to display individual value
foreach ($_POST['Color'] as $select)
{
echo "You have selected :" .$select; // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

**In your code you can try:**

```
    <?php 
         foreach($_POST['detaliicomanda'] as $select){
         echo "You have selected: ".$select;//Displaying selected value
         }
     ?>
```

Comment: i still didnt figure out how to setup :( is there a way that you can help me in private?

Comment: i have tryied both scripts that you guys writed here but seems the script doesn't want to take the data from <option value="X"> DATA <option>

Answer (score 1):

Only the value is sent to the server. You can use an associative array on the server to convert from the value to the text.

```
$detaliicomanda = array(
    'canapea' => 'Canapea',
    'fotoliu' => 'Fotoliu',
    ...
);
```

Then you can do:

```
$comanda = array_map(function($x) use($detaliicomanda) {
    return $detaliicomanda[$x];
}, $_POST['detaliicomanda']);
```